# Writing GPX file to sdcard from geopoints (ArrayList)

Tags: java, android

My application tracks the distance and shows the result in km on the screen. I save the geopoints in an ArrayList. I’d like to export the geopoints as a GPX track file to my sdcard.

I tried https://sourceforge.net/projects/gpxparser/. But after the command GPXParser p = new GPXParser(); my app crashes. (I couldn’t find out how to “instantiate the GPXParser class”, maybe that’s why it didn’t work).
Importing GPX files works flawless with this approach http://android-coding.blogspot.de/2013/01/get-latitude-and-longitude-from-gpx-file.html

Could anyone point me in a direction or give me a hint. I’ve search a lot, but couldn’t find anything I could get to work.

Update!

I've found a solution. Maybe not perfect, but it works.
To save my track, I use the following from my Map-Activity.
Maybe some has a better solution :-).

```
  public void saveRoute(String filename) {
    Toast.makeText(this, mTrace.size() + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    String fileName = filename;

    // routeFile = new File(getFilesDir(), FILENAME);

    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File myDir = new File(root + "/kml");
    myDir.mkdirs();

    File file = new File(myDir, fileName + ".gpx");

    savegpx gpxFile = new savegpx();
    try {
        file.createNewFile();
        gpxFile.writePath(file, fileName, mTrace);

        //   Log.i(TAG, "Route Saved " + file.getName());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("WritingFile", "Not completed writing" + file.getName());
    }
}
```

Separate class

```
public class savegpx {
private static final String TAG = savegpx.class.getName();
public savegpx() {
}

/**
 * Writes locations to gpx file format
 *
 * @param file file for the gpx
 * @param n name for the file
 * @param points List of locations to be written to gpx format
 */
public static void writePath(File file, String n, ArrayList<GeoPoint> points) {
    final Context applicationContext= MainActivity.getContextOfApplication();
    String header = "<gpx creator=\"Off-Road Tracker\" version=\"1.1\" xmlns=\"http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"  xsi:schemaLocation=\"http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd\">\n";
    String metadata = " <metadata>\n" + "   <time>1900-01-01T00:00:00Z</time>" + "\n  </metadata>";
    String name = " <trk>\n  <name>" + n + "</name>\n  <trkseg>\n";

    String segments = "";
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");


    List<String> stockList = new ArrayList<String>();






        for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++) {

            stockList.add("   <trkpt lat=\"" + (points.get(i)).getLatitude() + "\" lon=\"" + (points.get(i)).getLongitude() + "\">\n    <ele>" +(points.get(i).getAltitude()) + "</ele>\n    <time>" + df.format(new Date()) + "Z</time>\n   </trkpt>\n");

    }

    segments +=stockList;
  segments =  segments.replace(",","");
   segments = segments.replace("[","");
   segments =  segments.replace("]","");

    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, segments, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    String footer = "  </trkseg>\n </trk>\n</gpx>";

    try {
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);

        writer.append(header);
        writer.append(metadata);
        writer.append(name);
        writer.append(segments);
        writer.append(footer);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();

        Log.i(TAG, "Saved " + points.size() + " points.");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        //Toast.makeText(mapsActivity.getApplicationContext(),"File not found",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        Log.e(TAG, "Error Writting Path", e);
    }
}


}
```